# error using vue-cli-service build / npm run build on shared hosting (error creating worker pool)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

When I try to build my Vue project on a shared hosting service, it shows an error:

[image: click this link to view the error]

But when I run `npm run build` on my local environment, it works just fine.

Error Details:

```
     Building for production.../home/intechpe/onlineku-admin/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:53
      throw new Error(`Failed to create the worker pool with workerId: ${workerId} and ${''}configuration: ${JSON.stringify(options)}. Please verify if you hit the OS open files limit.`);
      ^

Error: Failed to create the worker pool with workerId: 4 and configuration: {"parallelJobs":20}. Please verify if you hit the OS open files limit.
    at new PoolWorker (/home/intechpe/onlineku-admin/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:53:13)
    at WorkerPool.createWorker (/home/intechpe/onlineku-admin/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:337:23)
    at WorkerPool.distributeJob (/home/intechpe/onlineku-admin/node_modules/thread-loader/dist/WorkerPool.js:331:28)
    at runQueue (/home/intechpe/onlineku-admin/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:8097:9)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! onlineku-admin@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the onlineku-admin@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/intechpe/.npm/_logs/2019-05-17T09_44_00_691Z-debug.log
```

Comment: add your error in the question.. see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Which hosting service are you using?

Comment: I'm using Domainesia shared hosting service, but its in Bahasa Indonesia if you want to check it

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

And found that it was caused by insufficient memory.

So that `thread-loader` can't work .

Maybe you should free up some memory usage

Answer (score 0):

Previously I'm facing same issue on cPanel ssh when running `npm run build`. But it's work when I'm using this command:

`npx vue-cli-service build`